# I can't download .xml file from webserver apache2

Tags: download, apache2

I'm new here, and I hope someone can help me with Apache2.
I need to configure Apache to download any `.xml` files, instead of displaying the content.

I have no idea how to do this, and any light or direction that anyone can share on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the "displaying", so I understand that you try to get xml from server by brawser. If you really want to change behavior of getting any XML files from server (or from some folder) you can rewrite Mime-header of XML to application/binary. This is in config, you should search mime.conf or like it. Restart server after edit configs. After it Your brawser (and ALL OTHER requests to your server will get XML with header **application/binary**, then usual applications (and Your brawser) does not know what to do with that content and just will save it. There is some nuances, ex: Some applications can be coded hardly to interpet content as XML, then it nevermind mime-header.